# (JavaScript) Store data from larger Array to a smaller Array with other key attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, split, store

Today I'm busy with storing data from a larger Array to a smaller Array, but with different key attributes. The smaller Array contains also less keys, so I have to split or remove keys from the larger one.

This is the structure of the two Arrays:

> **Array one (larger one):** brand:value, category:value, id:value, name:value, price:value, quantity:value, variant:value
>
> **Array two (smaller one):** item:value, quantity:value, price:value, unique_id:value

As you can notice, some keys are (almost) ready to insert into the smaller Array, but I still need to split the large Array. Or is it possible to select the keys you want and then insert it into the smaller Array? Anyway, can someone help me out with this?

*Nick.*

Comment: This new array is smaller in length also or only in terms of attributes? is there a one on one mapping between attributes of both array?

Comment: Are we talking about [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) or [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with a nested loop, one for the array and one for the wanted properties.

```js
function getParts(array, parts) {
    return array.map(function (a) {
        var temp = {};
        parts.forEach(function (k) {
            temp[k] = a[k];
        });
        return temp;
    });
}

var array = [{ brand: 'abc', category: 't1', id: 101, name: 'aaa', price: 30, quantity: 10, variant: 'q' }, { brand: 'abc', category: 't1', id: 102, name: 'bbb', price: 28, quantity: 20, variant: 'q' }, { brand: 'def', category: 't1', id: 103, name: 'ccc', price: 40, quantity: 30, variant: '' }, { brand: 'def', category: 't2', id: 104, name: 'ddd', price: 90, quantity: 40, variant: '' }, { brand: 'ghi', category: 't2', id: 105, name: 'eee', price: 12, quantity: 50, variant: 'q' }, { brand: 'ghi', category: 't2', id: 105, name: 'fff', price: 1, quantity: 60, variant: 'q' }];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getParts(array, ['quantity', 'price', 'id']), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I voted up, thanks for the support! This will help me out.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming for an array of objects* You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```js
var kvArray = [{
  key: 1,
  value: 10
}, {
  key: 2,
  value: 20
}, {
  key: 3,
  value: 30
}];
var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(function(obj) {
  return {
    "NewProperty": obj.key
  };
});

console.log(reformattedArray)
```

Comment: Thanks for the support!